# Display pylint error with pylint score for every file

Tags: python, command-line, pylint

I am trying to find a script which can lint a python file and then display the score of the python file.

```
find . -name '*.py' -print -exec pylint {} \; | egrep 'py$|has been rated'
```

Currently when i use the above script i am able to get the score of every python file but i also need to display the error along with the score. What would be the changes required to get both displayed together?

Current output which i am getting :

```
find . -name '*.py' -print -exec pylint {} \; | egrep 'py$|has been rated'
./admin/asgi.py
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
./admin/settings.py
Your code has been rated at 8.53/10 (previous run: 8.53/10, +0.00)
./admin/urls.py
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
./admin/wsgi.py
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
./admin/__init__.py
```

Expected output :

```
./admin/asgi.py
*suggestions to improve the pylint score for this file*
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
./admin/settings.py
*suggestions to improve the pylint score for this file*
Your code has been rated at 8.53/10 (previous run: 8.53/10, +0.00)
./admin/urls.py
*suggestions to improve the pylint score for this file*
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
./admin/wsgi.py
*suggestions to improve the pylint score for this file*
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
./admin/__init__.py
```

Comment: Would `egrep -B 1 ` to have egrep print the 1 line before the match do the trick?

Comment: are u telling to use it like this ? 
    find . -name '*.py' -print -exec pylint {""} \; | egrep -B 1 'py$|has been rated'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use `pylint . --recursive=y` if your pylint version is above `2.13.0`

> Add --recursive option to allow recursive discovery of all modules and packages in subtree. Running pylint with --recursive=y option will check all discovered .py files and packages found inside subtree of directory provided as parameter to pylint.

https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/whatsnew/2/2.13/full.html#what-s-new-in-pylint-2-13-0

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the below command to get the score as well as suggestion to improve the score.

```
find . -name '*.py' -print -exec pylint {} \;
```

This is the output i was expecting to get using the pylint command.

```
$ find . -name '*.py' -print -exec pylint {} \;
./cc_admin_console/admin/asgi.py

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)

./cc_admin_console/admin/settings.py
************* Module admin.settings
cc_admin_console\admin\settings.py:161:0: C0304: Final newline missing (missing- 
final-newline)
cc_admin_console\admin\settings.py:36:0: C0103: Constant name "default_hosts" 
 doesn't conform to UPPER_CASE naming style (invalid-name)
cc_admin_console\admin\settings.py:16:0: C0411: standard import "from datetime 
import timedelta" should be placed before "from dotenv import load_dotenv, 
find_dotenv" (wrong-import-order)
cc_admin_console\admin\settings.py:17:0: C0411: standard import "import os" 
should be placed before "from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv" (wrong- 
import-order)
cc_admin_console\admin\settings.py:18:0: C0411: standard import "import 
mimetypes" should be placed before "from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv" 
(wrong-import-order)

------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 8.53/10 (previous run: 8.53/10, +0.00)
```